# Run netlogo in parallel mpi using Sun Grid Engine

Tags: bash, mpi, netlogo, sungridengine

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N new
#$ -q all.q
#$ -pe mpi 30
unset SGE_ROOT
/opt/mpi/1.8.1/bin/mpirun -np $NSLOTS -hostfile $TMPDIR/machines /home/abhishekb/netlogo/netlogo-5.2.0/netlogo-headless.sh \
    --model /home/abhishekb/scale_med/try4.nlogo \
    --experiment experiment1 \
    --table /home/abhishekb/Trash/anything.csv
```

Error:

```
The: Command not found.
queuing: Command not found.
time-to-exit: Command not found.
Badly placed ()'s.
```

Output:

```
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
A hostfile was provided that contains at least one node not
present in the allocation:

  hostfile:  /tmp/8396.1.all.q/machines
  node:      compute-0-1
If you are operating in a resource-managed environment, then only
nodes that are in the allocation can be used in the hostfile. You
may find relative node syntax to be a useful alternative to
specifying absolute node names see the orte_hosts man page for
further information.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

PE file:

```
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/8396.1.all.q/rsh': No such file or directory
```

Earlier, I used to run the below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N new
#$ -q all.q
#$ -pe mpi 30
/home/abhishekb/netlogo/netlogo-5.2.0/netlogo-headless.sh \
    --model /home/abhishekb/std_low/try4.nlogo \
    --experiment experiment1 \
    --table /home/abhishekb/Trash/anything.csv \
    --threads 30
```

which simply processes on just one core (on checking at HPC end)though it grabs 30

Edit:

Doc for submitting jobs:
http://it.iiitd.edu.in/HPC_final_doc.pdf Please refer page 4 and 5 section 10 `Job subsmission steps.

Submitted job by `qsub <filename.sh>`

Comment: From what I can see, this looks like a submission issue. You should give more details on how you submitted your job through the batch scheduler.

Comment: I tried to add [sungridengine] as tag to your post and put SGE in the title, since I'm pretty sure this is where your problem comes from, but the edit was rejected... I really encourage you look in that direction though. Unfortunately, I do not have myself sufficient expertise with this specific batch scheduler to be of any further help.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the reply. Please check the edit in the question.

Comment: It looks like something you need to take up with your cluster administrators.

Comment: @Gilles `qsub <filename.sh>` to submit job.

Comment: What type of program are you running? Are you trying to run a MPI program across 30 compute nodes? Or is there OpenMP involved too? At least on my machine `-pe machineType 40` will grab 2 compute nodes (for MPI) because each has 20 processors/node (for OpenMP). What exactly are you trying to run?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll, he is running NetLogo - a Java program that has no idea of MPI whatsoever. Apparently, he wants to use MPI in order to start multiple copies simultaneously.